# complex integration cauchy theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the integral of the following assuming a simple closed path.

$f(z) = e^z - \frac{1}{z^2}$ along the lower half of the unit circle with center at the origin traversed in the clockwise direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited your question, is that what you meant ?

Comment: Is the function $f(z)$ given by $f(z)=e^z-\frac{1}{z^2}$?

Comment: yes this is correct

Comment: The path you describe is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus. An antiderivative of $f$ (valid on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$) is given by $F(z) = e^z + \dfrac{1}{z}$.